# ERROR: clBuildProgram(CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE)

Tags: c++, opencl, rcpp

I am working on a package for R using C++, Rcpp and OpenCL.

I am having a build failure when loading from a .cl file.
However, when I load from a const char * kernel it works.

```
// code build fails 
  std::ifstream sourceFile("Kernels.cl");
    std::string sourceCode( std::istreambuf_iterator<char(sourceFile), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

cl::Program::Sources  source(1, std::make_pair(sourceCode.c_str(), sourceCode.length()));  
// code build passes

cl::Program::Sources  source(1, std::make_pair(vadd, strlen(vadd)));
cl::Program program2 = cl::Program(context,source);
```

Is there an issue with loading OpenCL between rcpp and OpenCL?

Minimal Example( all dealing with an R package):
    Test.cpp

```
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
/* Modified from https://github.com/HandsOnOpenCL/Exercises-Solutions; Simon McIntosh-Smith and Tom Deakin from the University of Bristol*/

#include < /Users/5kd/Documents/TestExample/src/err_code.h >  
#include < /Users/5kd/Documents/TestExample/src/cl.hpp >
#include < vector >
#include < stdio >
#include < cstdlib >
#include < string >
#include < iostream >
#include < stream >
#include < /Users/5kd/Documents/TestExample/src/Test_Kernels.h >
#ifndef DEVICE
#define DEVICE CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT
#endif 


void TestVal1(){
        try{
                cl::Context context(DEVICE);
                cl_int err;
                std::ifstream sourceFile("Test_Kernels.cl");
                std::string sourceCode( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
                cl::Program::Sources  source1(1, std::make_pair(sourceCode.c_str(), sourceCode.length()));
                cl::Program program1(context,source1 );
                std::vector<cl::Device> devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
                program1.build(devices);
                Rcpp::Rcout << "pass 1\n";
        }
        catch (cl::Error err) {
                Rcpp::Rcout << "Exception\n";
                 Rcpp::Rcout << "ERROR: "<< err.what() << "("  << err_code(err.err()) << ")"  << "\n";
    }
};
void TestVal2(){
        try{
                cl::Context context(DEVICE);
                cl_int err;
                std::ifstream sourceFile2("vadd.cl");
                std::string sourceCode2( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile2), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
                cl::Program::Sources  source2(1, std::make_pair(sourceCode2.c_str(), sourceCode2.length()));
                cl::Program program2(context,source2 );
                std::vector<cl::Device> devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
                program2.build(devices);
                Rcpp::Rcout << "pass 2\n";
        }
        catch (cl::Error err) {
                Rcpp::Rcout << "Exception\n";
                 Rcpp::Rcout << "ERROR: "<< err.what() << "("  << err_code(err.err()) << ")"  << "\n";
    }
};
void TestVal3(){
        try{
                cl::Context context(DEVICE);
                cl_int err;
                cl::Program::Sources source3(1, std::make_pair(VAdd, strlen(VAdd)));
                cl::Program program3(context,source3 );
                std::vector<cl::Device> devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
                program3.build(devices);
                Rcpp::Rcout << "pass 3\n";
         }
        catch (cl::Error err) {
                Rcpp::Rcout << "Exception\n";
                 Rcpp::Rcout << "ERROR: "<< err.what() << "("  << err_code(err.err()) << ")"  << "\n";
    }
};
SEXP solve_(){
  Test opt;
  int soln = opt.region(5);
  return List::create();
}

int Test::region(int p){
  TestVal1();
  TestVal2();
  TestVal3();

  return(p);
};

Test::Test() {};
```

Test_Kernels.cl

```
kernel void vadd2( global const float *a , global const float * b ,global float *c ){

        int index= get_global_id(0);
        c]index] = a[index] + b[index];
}
```

vadd.cl

```
__kernel void vadd(
   __global float* a,
   __global float* b,
   __global float* c,
   const unsigned int count)
{
   int i = get_global_id(0);
   if(i < count)  {
       c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
   }
 }
```

Test_Kernels.h

```
const char * VAdd =" kernel void vadd( global const  float *a, global const float *b, global float* c){ int i = get_global_id(0);  c[i] = a[i] + b[i];         }";

    }
```

RcppExports.cpp

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// solve_
SEXP solve_();
RcppExport SEXP TestExample_solve_() {
BEGIN_RCPP
    SEXP __sexp_result;
    {
        Rcpp::RNGScope __rngScope;
        SEXP __result = solve_();
        PROTECT(__sexp_result = Rcpp::wrap(__result));
    }
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return __sexp_result;
END_RCPP
}
```

RcppExports.R

```
solve_ <- function() {
    .Call('TestExample_solve_', PACKAGE = 'TestExample')
}
```

Test_solve.R

```
Test_solve <- function() {

  opt_ <- get_Test_opts()

  .Call('TestExample_solve_', PACKAGE = 'TestExample')
}
```

Main running:
     Test.R

```
require(RcppEigen)
require(Matrix)
require(TestExample)


t <- Test_solve()
```

Build Using:
R CMD build TestExample
R CMD INSTALL TestExample.tar.gz
Run:
R -f Test.R

```
Output from my run:
> require(RcppEigen)
Loading required package: RcppEigen
> require(Matrix)
Loading required package: Matrix
> require(TestExample)
Loading required package: TestExample
Loading required package: Rcpp
> 
> 
> t <- Test_solve()

Exception
ERROR: clBuildProgram(CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE)
Exception
ERROR: clBuildProgram(CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE)
pass 3
```

Comment: Can you bring this as a minimal example to rcpp-devel?  Charles Determan may be able to help you, not sure he'll spot it here.  I only played with OpenCL indirectly via (Rcpp)ArrayFire.

Comment: I can try and bring a minimal example but most what I am working on can't be shown.

Comment: Understood, many of us are in a similar situation. That does not stop most of us from being able to mock the full issue with a _small_ yet salient reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you so much for fast replay!

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful. Right now the only people able to answer your question are those that have encountered it before. Those that are willing to investigate are left out.

Comment: I added Minimal example. Please let me know if I need to add more.

Comment: What's in `err_code.h`? `cl.hpp` is the standard OpenCL header?

Comment: errr_code.h : is the errors for opencl output. from the example I started using: https://github.com/HandsOnOpenCL/Exercises-Solutions. The cl.hpp is standard OpenCL header file

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an relation to Rcpp, since I am able to reproduce the compilation errors using a plain C++ program:

```
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS

#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void TestVal1(){
  try{
    cl::Context context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    std::ifstream sourceFile("Test_Kernels.cl");
    std::string sourceCode( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    cl::Program::Sources  source1(1, std::make_pair(sourceCode.c_str(), sourceCode.length()));
    cl::Program program1(context, source1);
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
    program1.build(devices);
    std::cout << "pass 1\n";
  }
  catch (cl::Error err) {
    std::cout << "Exception\n";
    std::cout << "ERROR: "<< err.what() << "("  << err.err() << ")"  << "\n";
  }
}
void TestVal2(){
  try{
    cl::Context context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    std::ifstream sourceFile("vadd.cl");
    std::string sourceCode( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    cl::Program::Sources  source2(1, std::make_pair(sourceCode.c_str(), sourceCode.length()));
    cl::Program program2(context, source2);
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
    program2.build(devices);
    std::cout << "pass 2\n";
  }
  catch (cl::Error err) {
    std::cout << "Exception\n";
    std::cout << "ERROR: "<< err.what() << "("  << err.err() << ")"  << "\n";
  }
}
void TestVal3(){
  try{
    cl::Context context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    const char * VAdd =" kernel void vadd( global const  float *a, global const float *b, global float* c){ int i = get_global_id(0);  c[i] = a[i] + b[i];         }";
    cl::Program::Sources source3(1, std::make_pair(VAdd, strlen(VAdd)));
    cl::Program program3(context, source3);
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
    program3.build(devices);
    std::cout << "pass 3\n";
  }
  catch (cl::Error err) {
    std::cout << "Exception\n";
    std::cout << "ERROR: "<< err.what() << "("  << err.err() << ")"  << "\n";
  }
}

int main(){
  TestVal1();
  TestVal2();
  TestVal3();
}
```

I both cases there where simple syntax errors in the kernels. Using

```
kernel void vadd2( global const float *a , global const float * b ,global float *c ){

        int index= get_global_id(0);
        c[index] = a[index] + b[index]; // [ instead of ]
}
```

and

```
__kernel void vadd(
   __global float* a,
   __global float* b,
   __global float* c,
   const unsigned int count)
{
   int i = get_global_id(0);
   if(i < count)  {
       c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
   }
} // missing
```

the example builds and runs fine, also from Rcpp:

```
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <fstream>

void TestVal1(){
  try{
    cl::Context context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    std::ifstream sourceFile("Test_Kernels.cl");
    std::string sourceCode( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    cl::Program::Sources  source1(1, std::make_pair(sourceCode.c_str(), sourceCode.length()));
    cl::Program program1(context,source1 );
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
    program1.build(devices);
    Rcpp::Rcout << "pass 1\n";
  }
  catch (cl::Error err) {
    Rcpp::Rcout << "Exception\n";
    Rcpp::Rcout << "ERROR: "<< err.what() << "("  << err.err() << ")"  << "\n";
  }
}
void TestVal2(){
  try{
    cl::Context context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    std::ifstream sourceFile2("vadd.cl");
    std::string sourceCode2( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile2), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    cl::Program::Sources  source2(1, std::make_pair(sourceCode2.c_str(), sourceCode2.length()));
    cl::Program program2(context,source2 );
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
    program2.build(devices);
    Rcpp::Rcout << "pass 2\n";
  }
  catch (cl::Error err) {
    Rcpp::Rcout << "Exception\n";
    Rcpp::Rcout << "ERROR: "<< err.what() << "("  << err.err() << ")"  << "\n";
  }
}
void TestVal3(){
  try{
    cl::Context context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
    const char * VAdd =" kernel void vadd( global const  float *a, global const float *b, global float* c){ int i = get_global_id(0);  c[i] = a[i] + b[i];         }";
    cl::Program::Sources source3(1, std::make_pair(VAdd, strlen(VAdd)));
    cl::Program program3(context,source3 );
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
    program3.build(devices);
    Rcpp::Rcout << "pass 3\n";
  }
  catch (cl::Error err) {
    Rcpp::Rcout << "Exception\n";
    Rcpp::Rcout << "ERROR: "<< err.what() << "("  << err.err() << ")"  << "\n";
  }
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void tests(){
  TestVal1();
  TestVal2();
  TestVal3();
}
```

To compile and run this file I use:

```
Sys.setenv(PKG_LIBS = "-lOpenCL")
Rcpp::sourceCpp("kernel_test.cpp")
tests()
```

Comment: The example case is broken down not to use the Rcpp info that is need, but the structure is the same. Will update the add kernel ( as it does the the last } ) int my case. also added the fix for the vadd2 kernel. Both still fail.

Comment: Most of the all of the code relate  to Rcpp I can not show.

Comment: @Kirsten I have added my working Rcpp code. Without an example that demonstrates the error we won't be able to help you.

Comment: So its a non reproducible error for you. With the example I gave. However,  it is a example of the error on my end that. Were you using gnu compilers?

Comment: @Kirsten I am using GCC 6.3.0 on Debian stable together with R 3.5.1 and Rcpp 0.12.18. What du you use? Do my examples (plain C++ and Rcpp) work for you?

Comment: I am working on OS X with Clang LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1). I have to make sure its able to work on all compilers and Operating systems. Using R 3.5.1, using Rcpp Version: 0.12.17

Comment: yes your examples all pass for me and the examples in the github examples work as well. Which is why I am partially confused.

Comment: @Kirsten The official compiler for R 3.5.x on Mac OS X is Clang 6 (cf https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/ and https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/). If that does not help, then you will have to find the difference between your code and my code that makes it fail. Creating a truly minimal example often helps with that.